# Problems loading Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

We recently had a power outage in the office and one of our ubuntu servers isn´t booting up properly. Here is what I have deduced so far:

- The motherboard seems fine and it allows me to enter the BIOS / UEFI settings.
- The only gurantee I have regarding the power source is that, again, it
  lets me see the UEFI settings and...
- I can boot a live USB with Ubuntu Desktop in order to trouble shoot a little more
- The SSD still has all the information intact. I have connected it to an ubuntu desktop machine and saw that it is all still there...
- When I simply restart the machine I´m faced with a dark screen (The pixels are on, but they´re black)

Where do you reckon I should look into next? I´m thinking it could be an issue with GRUB, but I´m not too sure.

EDIT: Ended up being the motherboard. For some reason there was a setting that would only allow for Windows boot manager to show. As soon as I deselected the option I was able to boot ubuntu with relative normality. I know this ended up not being ubuntu's fault but I'm just going to leave this up as it is since it might be helpful for someone else in the future.

Comment: Can you include which setting you changed or what is it called ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the setting called "boot mode" or something similar to that. I am the one of five people who have physical access to the server and I really doubt someone else would have touched it, which seems really odd. The setting only had two options:
- Windows mode
- Other OS

I found it extremely odd since I was also able to boot up other OS's using a USB stick and while this was set to "Windows mode". I think it's always been like that.. I turned off Secure boot and changed this weird setting to "Other OS" and after that it just booted up normally. This was an Asus motherboard by the way.